# how to remove menu's border in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi i have a menu control in asp.net....i write below code for that...and i bind the menu itemss dynamically..

```
    DataView viewItem = new DataView(table);
    viewItem.RowFilter = "Id=" + menuItem.Value;
    foreach (DataRowView childView in viewItem)
    {
        DataSet ds = da.GetDataSet("select top 5 Id,PageName,PageLink from Tbl_MstPageMaster where ModuleId = " + childView["Id"].ToString() + " and IsActive = 'true'");
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PageName"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Id"].ToString());
                childItem.NavigateUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PageLink"].ToString();
                menuItem.ChildItems.Add(childItem);

                //AddChildItems(table, childItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

here i need to change menu's bacKground color and remove default border...how to remove thaT...anybody suggest me..

Comment: You can use CSS to change the style, See [this article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Css

```
#Menu ul li a, 
#Menu ul li a:active {outline:none;}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So you should write CSS for it

```
#YourMenuID
{
background-color: red or #customcolor;
color:white;
border:0px none;
}
```

Where `#` is the menu id

And call the style sheet in your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="pathofyourstylesheet"/>
```